# Is it ok to read こみち as komiti?

Tags: pronunciation, hiragana

I think it should probably be pronounced as komichi or komich.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[ち](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_%28kana%29)** is often [transcribed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese) as **ti** natively in Japan and by scholars, because it is very nice to get a *simple* progression like **ta ti tu te to** for **たちつてと**, which can help when explaining various linguistic changes.

What happens in Japanese is that the vowels /**i**/ and /**u**/ [affect the previous sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#Palatalization_and_affrication), hence the sometime need to to more accurately describe this pronunciation. Usually this gets done as **chi** in English.

(Some non-IPA transcriptions of **ち** in languages other than English: chi, çi, či, ĉi, csi, ti.)

[As for IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), it is possible to transcribe on several *levels*:

- Very broadly: /**ti**/
- Broadly: /**tˢi**/
- Narrowly: [**tɕi**]

As far as I am aware [**tɕi**] is the standard IPA transcription of **ち** in modern, standard Japanese.

Comment: I don't think you can analyse ち as /ti/ any more, given the existence of words such as パーティー.

Comment: True, which is why I wrote “very broadly”. And the usage of a modifier **s** /ˢ/ is certainly not strict IPA either (but accepted as an extended convention). As usual, it all comes down to how you define things and where you draw the lines...

Comment: I doubt that Japanese has /tˢ/ either as phoneme or sound, at least for the way it's often used to transcribe a variation of /t/ that English speakers make. Do you mean /ts/?

Comment: No, I’ve seen it used just like that. Remember, they all are mere conventions used in broad transcriptions.

Looking up Japanese in the [Handbook of the International Phonetic Association: A Guide to the Use of the International Phonetic Alphabet](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/content/handbook-ipa) (Cambridge University Press, 1999), Hideo Okada also uses /tˢi/ mentioning that “/tˢ/ is normally [ts] but becomes [tɕ] before /i/.”

Comment: @AeonAkechi many languages have different phonologies for loans though; the way English speakers pronounce "Schadenfreude" or "Third Reich" can't really be justified to say that /x/ has become a phoneme in English. Another explanation for パーティー is simply that it's considered an English loan, and pronounced by speakers to the best of their ability at English phonology. I remember also reading a paper that showed that many speakers contrast /r/ from /l/ in loans and are statistically far more likely to pronounce them like the source language, though Katakana doesn't write it down.

Comment: @Zorf 'Schadenfreude' doesn't include /x/ to begin with (/ʃaːdənfʀɔʏdə/ in German I believe, generally /ʃɑːdənfɹɔɪdə/ in English, and 'Reich' is pronounced /ʀaɪç/ in German, and generally /ɹaɪk/ in English).

Comment: @AeonAkechi, yeah but "Reich" does, and is often pronounced with /x/ in English. I just looked it up on Wiktionary and it lists both  /ɹaɪx/, and /ɹaɪk/ as acceptable pronunciations. "Schadenfreude" is often pronounced with a German [ʀ] in English to the best of the speaker's ability, that doesn't normally occur in English. Loans often have phones and contrasts that don't necessarily exist in the host language. There are also katakana combinations スィ now and シィ, as well as フゥ; I've seen "food" transcribed as フゥード in the wild, indicating a contrast of h/f even before /u/.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't use quotation marks, your question is a bit ambiguous.

こみち can be *transcribed* as "komiti" using [Nihon-shiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihon-shiki_romanization)/[Kunrei-shiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunrei-shiki_romanization) romanization (see this [relevant paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunrei-shiki_romanization#Usage)).

But it is *pronounced* as "komichi" or [/komit͡ʃi/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) (although I'm no IPA expert).

Comment: [komitɕi] or [kòmítɕì] (or whatever the tones are) is probably more accurate, but you have the right idea.